# Tensorflow 1.2 Android Demo and Hexagon (Qualcomm 835)

Tags: android, tensorflow, hexagon-dsp

Will Tensorflow 1.2 Android Demo utilize Hexagon (Qualcomm 835) or not? More general question:  does Tensorflow 1.2 for Android (from jcenter) include specific code for supporting Hexagon?

PS
Previously it was not supported according [TensorFlow HVX Acceleration support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948719/tensorflow-hvx-acceleration-support)

Comment: @pete-warden do you know if it will be supported?